# Why can't I call operator()?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand different topics in C++ by examples and I cannot get this example to work:

```
template<typename T>
class zero_init
{
    T val;
public:
    zero_init() : val(static_cast<T>(0)) { std::cout << "In constructor with no parameters\n"; }
    operator T() const { std::cout << "In operator T()\n";  return val; }
};

int main()
{
    const zero_init<int> x;
    x(); //Error!
    return 0;
}
```

I am obviously trying to call the operator() but it gives the error: "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator()"

Comment: You don't have operator(). You have operator T() (i.e. a conversion).

Comment: if your `operator()` takes no parameters it should be declared as `T operator()() const`

Comment: @MarcGlisse I updated the code (added a parameter by accident)

Comment: I.e. you should call it with the int argument

Comment: @AMA I have already tried that, but it yields the exact same error

Comment: @Noe no [it doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eRFQBptIARTLRvmo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally implemented a type conversion operator and not `operator()`. Overload `operator()` like this instead (I removed the return value because you discard it in `main` anyway):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class zero_init
{
    T val;
public:
    zero_init() : val(static_cast<T>(0)) { std::cout << "In constructor with no parameters\n"; }
    void operator()() const { std::cout << "In operator()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    const zero_init<int> x;
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

If you actually need the return value, do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class zero_init
{
    T val;
public:
    zero_init() : val(static_cast<T>(0)) { std::cout << "In constructor with no parameters\n"; }
    T operator()() const { std::cout << "In operator()\n"; return val; }
};

int main()
{
    const zero_init<int> x;
    auto val = x();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyway, since I cannot accept an answer before 9 minutes - you state "If you actually need the return value, do it like this:", how come it works without the specification of the return type?

Comment: @Noe: Because in the first example I turned it into a `void` function.

Comment: Like this operator works great: "operator T&() { std::cout << "In operatorT&\n";  return val; }"

Comment: @Noe: Not sure I understand. `operator T&()` would be another type conversion operator. `operator()` is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Forget it all haha. I understand it now :)